# Unit Testing - Ensure all repositories pass through the constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to create a unit test method to ensure that all repositories are being passed through the constructor.

I believe that using Moq repositories may be the best solution here, but so far I have not been able to verify that the test method passes.

Controller:

```cs
public AgentsController(ICallBoardStatsRepo callBoardRepo)
{
    _callBoardRepo = callBoardRepo;
}
```

Interface:

```cs
public interface ICallBoardStatsRepo:IDisposable
{
    CallBoardStats ById(int clientId);
    ClientCalls ByIdNavStats(int clientId);
}
```

My current test method for the repository constructor looks like the following:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void AgentController_Test()
{
    var myCallBoard = new Mock<AgentCallStats>();
    var myTestCallBoard = new Mock<AgentCallStats>();

    var callBoardList = new List<AgentCallStats>() { myCallBoard.Object, myTestCallBoard.Object };
    var ICallBoard = new Mock<IAgentCallStatsRepo>();
    ICallBoard.Setup(x => x.ById(2)).Returns(callBoardList);

    myCallBoard.Verify(x => x.Equals(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
    myTestCallBoard.Verify(x => x.Equals(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
 }
```

When running the individual test method, I get an error looking something like:

> Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times

I am not very experienced in writing unit tests, and this is really throwing me for a loop. Would anyone be willing to help point me in the right direction? I feel like I am close to solving this, but maybe an extra set of eyes may be able to highlight the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You are checking Object.Equals for being executed. Is that intended?

Comment: If you take AAA as a stantard pattern, what is your Act part? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Johnny All that is required here is that the repository is able to pass through the controller constructor (AgentController). It may act better as a TestInitialize instead of a TestMethod here

Comment: @SamRR_75 Then Act block should be invocation of the ctor...